# VB.net Texbox Value not being updated to Public Shared Variable

Tags: vb.net, variables, textfield, shared

Im having a textfield set up with the text "Hello" and a button
When i change the text and press i'd like to have a msgbox replying the changed text

```
Public Class TestText
Dim Text As String = Textbox.text
Private Sub BtnchangeTXT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnchangeTXT.Click
Text = Textbox.Text
Msgbox(Text)
Msgbox(TextField.Fieldtext)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class TextField
    Public Shared FieldText As String = TestText.Textbox.Text
End Class
```

All works well untill i request for the "TextField.FieldText" msgBox this will always return the defaulttext ("hello")

where do i go wrong?
Ive tried to set a different text "On Load" but still the default "Hello" is being returned.

Comment: TestText is not a shared class, so there isn't one single copy of the textbox you can refer to from that. You need to get hold of the right instance of the class.

Comment: @evry1falls, for one thing, that would be impossible because there's no such thing as a `Shared` class. That would be a module. Secondly, even if there were `Shared` classes, if `TestText` contains a `TextBox` and a `Button` then it is presumably a form, so what would it mean to make a form class `Shared`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yes. I dunno why I thought that . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
Public Shared FieldText As String = TestText.Textbox.Text
```

The value of "FieldText" only gets set ONCE, when that variable is created (and that occurs even before the form with the textbox is shown).  It does not get updated whenever the TextBox changes.

If you want that variable to always have the current value of that TextBox, then use the TextChanged() event of that TextBox to update the variable.

```
Private Sub Textbox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Textbox.TextChanged
        TextField.Fieldtext = Textbox.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. Firstly, because this code:

```vb
Public Class TextField
    Public Shared FieldText As String = TestText.Textbox.Text
End Class
```

uses the name of the `TestText` class to refer to an instance of that class, it is referring to the default instance. If you don't know what default instances are, I suggest that you do some reading on the subject. You can find my own writeup [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

That means that that code will always get the `Text` of the `TextBox` on the default instance of that type. If you display the default instance then that's fine but if you explicitly create an instance and display that, then modify the contents of the `TextBox` on that instance, that will have exactly zero effect on the default instance.

The second issue is the fact that you are using a field. You seem to be under the impression that that `FieldText` field should change dynamically as you change the contents of the `TextBox`. Why would you think that? The code you have DOES NOT get the current contents of the `TextBox` every time you get the field value. What is does is get the current contents of the `TextBox` and assign it to the field on the first occasion you get that field and then NEVER changes the field value again. If what you actually want is the current contents of the `TextBox` then you would need a property rather than a field:

```vb
Public Class TextField
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property FieldText As String
        Get
            Return TestText.Textbox.Text
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The whole point of properties is that they act like fields on the outside, so your code to get that property value won't change, but they act like methods on the inside, so the code to get the current contents of the `TextBox` will be executed every time you get the property value.

Comment: Your explaination here definatelly pulled me over that line to read more about this.
Thank you for that. Although the answer of Idle_Mind got my code working for now. I Actually dont know if thats a quick fix (which, for now, works perfectly for me) or best solution. ill dive in to your writeup later today. it seems very educational.